# Loading webservlet after spring context is initialized

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

We use Spring MVC annotations.
I have a StartUpServlet as well. My requirement is to load this servlet after the FilterDispatcher servlet is initialized.

Basically, we would like to initialize the Google Guava cache and load the cache with the data from the table.

I can have a static block and load the data. But the problem is the class where we do the cache initialization and cache loading might be garbage collected if we never access it for long time.
So, though of having the cache loading class instance refernece inside a servlet so that it will never be garbage collected. But the servlet gets loaded before the FrameworkServlet dispatcher initialized and Dependency injections are working.

Looking for help on this ......

Thanks in Advance,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 0):

The cache does not actually need to be in a servlet, the simplest would be to put it inside a singleton bean that populates the cache at server startup time. The bean would look like this:

```
@Component("cacheBean")
public class MyCachedDataService implements InitializingBean {

    private MyCache cache;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        ... populate the cache ...
    }

    public void cacheLookup(String key) {
        ... lookup the cache ...
    }
}
```

The most important here would be to avoid making further changes to the cache after server startup, in order to avoid race conditions. The bean can then be injected in other beans using `@Autowired` as usual.